# Like Numerical Wildcard query not working in Access

Tags: ms-access

One of my query stopped to work after compact and repair in Access DB.

Before it can still see those wildcard numerical entry (records that has first three numbers) in `catalogNum` field. After the compact and repair, the query can't recognize them anymore.

Query:

`UPDATE [CurrTbl] 
 SET [CurrTbl].[Ref#] = Left([catalogNum],4)
 WHERE [catalogNum] Like "###*";`

Even `[catalogNum] Like "K#*"` doesn't work.

Here's the sample data:

[image]

The `catalogNum` format is Short Text. The target records were ID numbers 1 and 3, but the query does not return any records for update.

I recreated my table/query from scratch and still no luck.

Is my database corrupted? or something I missed on the query?

Access version: 1902 Build 11328.20420

**Edit:**

I used the **[0-9]** instead of **#** and it works. But it still wanders me how the # stopped working as a parameter in my file.

Comment: I had no problem running this query. It updated records 1 and 3. My version: 1902 build 11328.20438. Try doing a */decompile* and then compact and repair.

Comment: I tried to decompile the same database file and still no luck.

Comment: Look into the hidden sys tables, especifically MSysCompactErrors, you might have had a problem in there, like mentioned in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970228/problem-with-a-ms-access-query-after-a-compact-and-repair-operation?rq=1